# How to add @Override, @Deprecate and static modifiers to methods automatically for all project Java classes where necessary?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to insert [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) / [`@Deprecated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotations and static modifiers automatically where necessary to all Java files of concrete project is opened in Eclipse IDE.

Eclipse has a great ability to insert `@Override`/`@Deprecate` annotations and add static modifiers on Java files saving (`Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save actions -> Additional actions`). But Eclipse can apply these actions only on edited java file and only when saving it.

Sure, I can insert a tab or space into the each file using Eclipse as editor and save it to activate Eclipse refactoring tools on save action, but I have a very big code amount to process, so this is very nasty.

Maybe there is an Eclipse plugin which supports such type of code refactoring?

If there are no solutions, I`ll try to write my own Eclipse RCP plugin for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Right-click the project in the package explorer view -> a context menu appears
2. In that menu, choose "Source" and then "Clean Up ..." -> the clean up dialog appears
3. pick the desired actions, and click "Finish"

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to find this option in Project Explorer but I really forgot about Packege Explorer =)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by save actions. When you save the file, eclipse will automatically add these annotation for you.
Please follow the following setting:

Window => Preferences => Java => Editor => Save Actions, and check "Add missing @Override annotations'.