# Render function in Java

Tags: java, function, render

Hi I wonder if the render function in java is an override from another superclass and if so which one?

```
   public void render(Graphics g) {

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  I can find no class or interface in the Java SE class library (Java 9) that has a method with that signature.

Comment: For future reference, coders use IDEs for many reasons, and one of those reasons are so they can inquire into the family tree of any object or class they are interested in. In general, simple questions about specific API structure should be solved by your own research using the API documentation (or with an IDE, if you don't have the docs handy).

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE like `eclipse`, and that'll help you navigate the class tree faster. It can also insert `@Override` annotations automatically, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348456/1110636) answer for how to get that.